# remote access of window server 2008 wamp server

Tags: php

my localhost:8080 working on window server 2008 fine and there is no issue but when i access the the window server 2008 localhost with ip of the server and port address from other computer in a LAN they not responding 
**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.**

please help me i searching from many days but no specific answer get to solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on httpd.conf of apache

Normal: to allow connections from your computer only

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1  // localhost (your computer)
</Directory>
```

Change to:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all   // allow from all like a (webserver)
</Directory>
```